# OpenGL aliasing?

Tags: winforms, opengl, visual-studio-2008, antialiasing

I am working on win7 microsoft visual studio 08 with Forms. I just changed my graphic card and some kind of aliasing appears in my application.

[image: img]

It can be apreciated that the grey lines are kind of aliased, and also the reference system, that is almost invisible.

Any idea of how to solve this?

I'll post some part of the code just in case:
1: Paint function

```
private: void Paint(){



        int w = glControl1->Width;
        int h = glControl1->Height;


        float aspect_ratio = w / (float)h;
        Matrix4 perpective = Matrix4::CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper::PiOver4, aspect_ratio, 0.1f, 100000.0f);
        GL::MatrixMode(MatrixMode::Projection);
        GL::LoadMatrix(perpective);

        GL::MatrixMode(MatrixMode::Modelview);
        GL::LoadIdentity();
        GL::Viewport(0, 0, w, h);

        //Situacion de la camara en el espacio
        Matrix4 lookat = Matrix4::LookAt(100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        GL::LoadMatrix(lookat);

        GL::Scale(this->zoom, this->zoom, this->zoom);


        GL::Rotate(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL::Rotate(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL::Clear(ClearBufferMask::ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask::DepthBufferBit);
           GL::ClearColor(Color::LightGray);



        Draw3Daxis();
        if (allowDraw){
            DrawSurface();
            }
        }
```

2: function that draws everything shown in the picture (it is just a bunch of GL::Vertex3)

```
System::Void Draw3Daxis(){
         OpcionesPlot* opciones;
         opciones=OpcionesPlot::Instance();
         int extra=2;
         int sqrnumber=10;

        //Planos en los ejes
        GL::Color3(Color::White);
        GL::Begin(BeginMode::Quads);
        if(opciones->draw3DXYaxis){
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH,LENGTH,0);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH,0);
         }
         if(opciones->draw3DXZaxis){
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(LENGTH,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(LENGTH,0,LENGTH);
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH);
         }
         if(opciones->draw3DYZaxis){
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH,0);
             GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH,LENGTH);
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH);
        }
         GL::End();


         // ejes XYZ
         GL::Color3(Color::Black);
         GL::Begin(BeginMode::Lines);
         if(opciones->draw3DXYaxis){
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra,0);
         }
         if(opciones->draw3DXZaxis){
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra);
         }
         if(opciones->draw3DYZaxis){
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra,0);
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,0);
             GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra);
        }

         //--> lineas de los planos
         GL::Color3(Color::DarkGray);
         for(int i=1;i<=sqrnumber;i++){
             if(i==sqrnumber)
                 GL::Color3(Color::Black);
             if(opciones->draw3DXYaxis){
                 GL::Vertex3(LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,0,0);
                 GL::Vertex3(LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,LENGTH,0);
                 GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,0);
                 GL::Vertex3(LENGTH,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,0);
             }
             if(opciones->draw3DXZaxis){
                 GL::Vertex3(LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,0,0);
                 GL::Vertex3(LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,0,LENGTH);
                 GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i);
                 GL::Vertex3(LENGTH,0,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i);

             }
             if(opciones->draw3DYZaxis){
                 GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i);
                 GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i);
                 GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,0);
                 GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH/sqrnumber*i,LENGTH);
             }

         }
        GL::End();
        // triangulos para los ejes
        //----->cuadrado
        GL::Color3(Color::Black);
        GL::Begin(BeginMode::Quads);
        float quadside=0.7;
        if(opciones->draw3DXYaxis){
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,-quadside);

            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);


         }
         if(opciones->draw3DXZaxis){
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,-quadside);

            GL::Vertex3(quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
         }
         if(opciones->draw3DYZaxis){
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);

            GL::Vertex3(quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);

        }
        GL::End();


        // --> triangulos para hacer la punta
        GL::Begin(BeginMode::Triangles);
        if(opciones->draw3DXYaxis){
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);

            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);

        }
        if(opciones->draw3DXZaxis){
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3((float)LENGTH+extra,quadside,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(LENGTH+extra+5,0,0);

            GL::Vertex3(quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);
         }
         if(opciones->draw3DYZaxis){
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,-quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra,quadside);
            GL::Vertex3(0,LENGTH+extra+5,0);

            GL::Vertex3(quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);
            GL::Vertex3(-quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,-quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(quadside,quadside,(float)LENGTH+extra);
            GL::Vertex3(0,0,LENGTH+extra+5);

        }
        GL::End();
        Write3D(LENGTH,3,3,GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15,"X");
        Write3D(3,LENGTH,3,GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15,"Y");
        Write3D(3,3,LENGTH,GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15,"Z");
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling depth testing before drawing each set of objects (reference planes first, axes second and then the reference grid).

It looks like your axes are Z-fighting the reference planes.

You have multiple options -

1. Disable depth test when drawing the lines (not the planes). This will make sure that no z-fighting occurs.
2. Keep depth testing on, but use glPolygonOffset when drawing the planes to offset them so that z-fighting does not happen at all.
3. Use GL_LEQUAL (or whatever else) as the DepthFunc when drawing the planes, but use GL_EQUAL when drawing the lines. This *should* make things ok.

Comment: mmm yes it actualy works that way but It gives me another problem. If I disable the depth test I can see throught the planes when rotating, and in some rotations it gets some crazy geometry...

Comment: Well in fact the weird geometies were wrong interpretations of the rotation (as you can see throught planes it seem to be in diferent rotation) .

Comment: Ah, don't disable the depth test while drawing the planes. Disable them afterward only to draw lines, everything should be ok.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't achieve to make any difference id disabling the depth test allways or only disabling it when drawing the lines. In fact it seems that if I disable the depth test only once, even if I enable it in the next line the depth test is disabled and everithing is drawn on top of the other.

Comment: Of course disbaling the depth test for the view of the image I posted is a solution, but look at the next image: [link](http://postimage.org/image/ns54txmgb/). It can apreciate thet the proyections drawn in the planes are drawn over the 3D surface. If there is no solution to this I can just not draw those proyections, they are not necesary, but still I like them and I would like to have them.

Comment: You image looks ok to me, what is the problem? Also see my edits, I have provided more options.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with the edit's you have made, thanks. The problen in the image is that the proyections in the planes (the line-made surface) is on top of the 3D surface, and it should be behind it.

Comment: Hi, it happens that I needed to go back to WinXP with my old GPU and with this one there is no Z-fighting anymore (it the generic GPU that is in the motherboard so it is quite bad). I am sorry I can not try your options but I think the 2 option specially will work. Thanks for the help!